# Multiply a Value from one table with all rows of a field on the second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. I want to multiply a single factor value from the currency table with all the rows of the Price field from the Product table.

```
Select Product.ID, (Product.Price* (select factor from Currency)) as NewPrice,
       Product.weight, Product.description
from Product,
     Currency
```

It does not seem to work. Please suggest the correct statement.

Comment: Does the Currency table only contain one, single row?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Remove `Currency` from the `from` clause to start with. Further select the correct currency in the subquery, i.e. something like `(select factor from Currency where ISO = Product.Currency_ISO)`

Comment: Just a general remark: Never use commas in the from clause. This is a syntax that was used in the 1980s and early 1990s. Since 1992 the SQL standard features explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, etc.). Use these instead of those outdated comma joins.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this (except the currency id on which you join the tables):

```
Select P.ID
      ,P.Price*C.factor as NewPrice
      ,P.weight
      ,P.description
from Product P
INNER JOIN Currency C
    ON P.[currencyID] = C.[currencyID]
```

Comment: currency_id has a single value, for example, currency_id is 7. There is no currency_id in the product table.

Comment: @bob24 you are not able to join the tables by yourself? if not, tell me the `Currency` columns

Comment: The currency table has currencyID, currency_name, currency_value, factor columns. I want to multiply the factor value from currencyID  7 with all the rows of the Price field in the Product table.

Comment: Anyone with a good answer.